# Removing duplicated lines from a textbox and getting the count of the removed lines. (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, count, duplicates, lines

**I am developing a bar management software, i did the most of the job but now i don't know the code to remove the same lines from a textbox and getting the number of the removed lines after they are removed.**

My code till now:

```
For Each saveitem As ListViewItem In Form1.ListView1.Items
        RichTextBox1.AppendText(saveitem.Text & vbNewLine)
        TextBox3.AppendText(saveitem.SubItems(1).Text & vbNewLine)
    Next
    RichTextBox1.AppendText(vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "TOTALI:" & "  " &  Form1.TextBoxX5.Text & vbNewLine & "TOTALI pa TVSH:" & "  " & TextBox4.Text)
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way :

```
'get array of individual line of text'
Dim textLines = TextBox3.Text.Split(New String(){vbNewLine}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)

Dim totalCount = textLines.Length
Dim noDuplicateCount = textLines.Distinct().Count()
'store number of lines removed'
Dim removedLinesCount = totalCount - noDuplicateCount

'join distinct line of texts by new line into single string'
TextBox3.Text = String.Join(vbNewLine, textLines.Distinct())
```